# Shopify and Liquid: Get product in an array for loop of product variant SKUs

Tags: loops, shopify, liquid, variant, sku

I'm trying to create a custom collection template on our Shopify store. Our business, every month, does a promotional update to our existing collections that ends up becoming a laborious chore with the manual collection curation of selecting individual SKUs. On our Wordpress/Woocommerce site, it's all easily handled with a comma separated list of of SKUs and the [products] shortcode.

I am trying to write a for loop with Liquid to loop through an array of SKUs, and display the product tile per SKU. The only thing is, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to target a specific product by product.variant.sku.

How I envision it from a simplistic view:

```
{% assign product_skus = "1234,5678,9101,1121" | split: ',' %}
{% for product_sku in product_skus %}
  {% if product.variant.sku == product_sku %}
    {% include "product-tile" %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know the above will not work, but I cannot find the proper direction in the documentation (or I'm just not understanding it correctly) to make this sort of thing work. I feel like it should be possible. Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to utilize the default input types to create a backend editor settings panel using input type `product_list` [documentation link](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#product_list).

```
{
  "type": "product_list",
  "id": "product_list",
  "label": "Products",
  "limit": 12
}
```

and loop them using liquid one front end easily.
add code `settings_schema.json`

[image]

it appears in the editor like this

[image]

Choose products
[image]

get the same into using liquid code like this sample

```
{% for product in settings.product_list %}
   {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]
[image]

Read more about product object in Shopify [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/product)

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I greatly appreciate you looking at this! I think this could be handy in a different application, it's just not quite what I'm looking to achieve.

I'm hoping to be able to paste a comma separated list of SKUs into a text field (for example purposes). Then do a split on that text field into an array, and then loop through SKUs with a for loop. This would be something I would figure would have to be done at the **Sections** level. I've kind of got something rigged up with a few ugly for loops and an "all" collection that I'm exploring.